# Replacing fields in a JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

The bottom line is that I have two JSON files and in one of them there are fields: `"string_action_ok": "OK"` and `"string_action_cancel": "Cancel"`, but in the other JSON file there is only one field: `"string_action_ok": "OK"`, and the field `"string_action_cancel": "Cancellation"` is missing. I need to replace the existing fields with new ones and add the ones that don't exist.

I tried to implement it through `str_replace` and `foreach`, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I finally solved this issue and share it with you. To achieve the result of replacing the existing keys, you should use the array_merge function, a small example:

`$array_replaced_keys = array_merge($array_old, $array_new);`

And so, what's going on here.. `$array_old` is an existing JSON array that we have converted into a list (Array), in the array $array_new there are new keys that will be applied instead of the existing keys in the array `$array_old`. Example:

`$array_old = json_decode('{"action_cancel":"Cancel", "action_ok": "OK", "action_confirm":"Confirm"}', true);`

We also proceed with the new array `$array_new`, example:

`$array_new = json_decode('{"action_confirm":"Confirm new"}', true);`

What we should end up with is:

```
$array_replaced_keys = array_merge($array_old, $array_new);
print_r(json_encode($array_replaced_keys)); // Result: {"action_cancel":"Cancel", "action_ok": "OK", "action_confirm":"Confirm new"}
```

Since there was only `"action_confirm"` in the new array, it was the only one and replaced the old version.

Answer (score -1):

You can use native php function [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
<?php

$arrayJson = [
    [
        "string_action_ok" => "OK",
        "string_action_cancel" => "Cancellation"
    ],
    "another" => [
        [
            "string_action_ok" => "OK",
            "string_action_cancel" => "Cancellation"
        ],
    ]
];

array_walk_recursive(
    $arrayJson,
    static function (&$value, $key) {
        if ($key === 'string_action_cancel') {
            $value = 'Cancel';
        }
    }
);

print_r($arrayJson);
```

Live code -> https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bGQj